# Dynamically adding counter to v-data-table with two buttons to increment and decrement and the number between them

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

The problem here is I am getting data from an api and the data has no property like 'count' so I need to create another array and use it in v-for.

But I want to specify a number with the counter and when the add button is clicked on each row, I want to add that object to a vuex state equal to the number in the counter.

Now when i click to the increment button all columns of counts are incrementing at the same time on all rows.

Also this button is in a different component and the count value will be dynamically passed to this component.

I tried to add td's to all rows but its incrementing in every single column.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the v-data-table:

```
<v-data-table dense :headers="dataTableHeaders" :items="filteredCoins" :items-per-page="5">

        <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="coin in items" :key="coin.symbol">
              <td>{{ coin.symbol }}</td>
              <td>{{ coin.lastPrice }}</td>
              <td>
                <v-btn icon x-small text @click.stop="counter++">
                  <v-icon>mdi-arrow-up</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-counter :value="counter" />
                <v-btn icon x-small text @click.stop="counter--">
                  <v-icon>mdi-arrow-down</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </td>
              <td v-if="$store.state.portfolio.includes(coin)">
                <UpdateDeleteButtons :selected-coin="coin" :count="counter"/>
              </td>
              <td v-else>
                <AddButton :selected-coin="coin" :count="counter"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </template>

      </v-data-table>
```

And here is the AddButton component:

```
<template>
  <v-btn x-small color="#0EDC79" @click="saveCoinToPortfolio()">
    Portfolyonuza Ekleyin
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
export default {
  props: {
    selectedCoin: [],
    count: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
    }
  },

  name: 'AddButton',

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['saveCoinToPortfolio']),

    saveCoinToPortfolio() {
      this.$store.dispatch('saveCoinToPortfolio', {data: this.selectedCoin, count: this.count})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have only one `counter` variable, which is used in all rows. Try adding the counter to your `coin` data, or if you do not want to change those, add a separate `coinCounter` object which stores counter by coin key (`coin.symbol`). It should look something like this:

```html
<v-btn icon x-small text @click.stop="coinCounter[coin.symbol]++">...
```

or

```html
<v-btn icon x-small text @click.stop="coin.counter++">...
```